# How to modify this Bootstrap column stacking behavior

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap 3.3.7, I have this markup:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Col 1 Main text goes here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      Col 2 List of links to other pages here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      Col 3 Sidebar text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As I reduce browser window size, I would expect Cols 2 and 3 to wrap below Col 1 but display alongside each other initially.

Instead, all three columns are stacked vertically after first break. How do I alter this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap the -md- denotes "medium". So as that is the only size you've set, bootstrap defaults will be used for when it's small. You can add different column numbers specifically for when the screen gets smaller using "col-sm" alongside the "col-md" like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      Col 1 Main text goes here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      Col 2 List of links to other pages here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
      Col 3 Sidebar text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can also hard-code columns by removing the "-md" section.

You can see an example at this codepen: 
https://codepen.io/jay-searra/pen/MzJvZg